# Handling concurrent file writes in Bash using SIGSTOP and SIGCONT

Tags: linux, bash, concurrency, signals

### Initial question :

My goal is to use signal systems to concurrently write to multiples files but by keeping the order of which scripts executed first wrote to the file (his *PID*) using a Bash script.

Here is the script that writes to three files (f1 f2 f3 in my script) concurrently.

For testing purposes, I always remove all the files f1,f2 and f3 to be able to re-use and verify that what was done by the script is always the same.

```
#! /bin/bash
# write_concurrently.sh
if [ -f f1 ] ; then
  rm f1 
fi
if [ -f f2 ] ; then
  rm f2 
fi
if [ -f f3 ] ; then
  rm f3 
fi
./write.sh f1 f2 f3 & ./write.sh f1 f2 f3
```

I have tried to concurrently write the *PID* of my script `write.sh` into each files (f1,f2 and f3).

To do this correctly, everytime the script `write.sh` is executed, it writes its *PID* to a file `file_PID`.

Then, it send a `SIGSTOP` signal to any *PID* inside the file `file_PID` and it begins writing to the file the *PID* of the script along with a string (first) that says whether he was the `"first <PID of script>"` to write his *PID* or not (if he's not the first then it writes `"next <PID of script>"`).

Once I have finished writing to the file, the *PID* of my script.
I remove the *PID* of my script (using a sed command) from the file `file_PID`.
Finally I send a `SIGCONT` signal for every *PID* contained inside the `file_PID` .

The code of `write.sh` :

```
#! /bin/bash
# write.sh content
file_PID="./file_PID"
if [ $# -lt 1 ] ; then
  echo "Need at least one parameter"
  exit 1
fi
echo $$ >> "$file_PID"
echo "My PID is : $$"
for elem in "$@" ; do
  if [ ! -e "$elem" ] ; then
    while read pid ;do
    if [ $pid -ne $$ ]; then 
        echo "PID : $$ Sent SIGSTOP to $pid"
            kill -SIGSTOP $pid
    fi
    done < "$file_PID"
    echo first $$ > "$elem"
  else
    echo next $$ >> "$elem"
  fi
  sed "/^$pid\$/d" $file_PID > $file_PID # Edit 1
  while read pid ; do  
    if [ $pid -ne $$ ]; then
        echo "PID : $$ Sent SIGCONT to $pid"
        kill -SIGCONT $pid
  done < $file_PID
done
```

When I do the tests, running `write_concurrently.sh`, I cannot understand the results I have they are completely inconsistent.

Running multiple times my script `write_concurrently.sh` leads to different outputs.

So no signals are sent in this case? However the files f1 f2 and f3 are created and contains respectively.

```
My PID is : 31614
My PID is : 31613
```

---

```
#f1 content
first 31614
next 31613
#f2 content
first 31614                                                                                                                                                                
next 31613
#f3 content
first 31613                                                                                                                                                           
next 31614
```

If I launch the script again here is another result that is different :

```
My PID is : 3468                                                                                                                                                           
My PID is : 3469
```

---

```
#f1 content
first 3468
next 3469

#f2 content
first 3469

#f3 content
first 3469
next 3468
```

Finally a third case that happens :

```
My PID is : 9016
PID : 9016 Sent SIGSTOP to 9017
```

The script of *PID* 9016 has finished but the *PID* 9017 is 
And the script hangs the terminal, unless I kill the *PID* or I send a `SIGCONT` signal from another terminal.
If I check the status of the *PID*, it is stopped.

```
  PID  PPID S
 9017  9012 T
```

But why did the script of *PID* 9016 didn't send the `SIGCONT` signal after having finished writing to the file, the script has finished his task if he is no longer alive.
The only thing I can think of, is that the *PID* 9016 paused the script 9017 before it could written his own *PID* into the file `file_PID` however that is impossible since he was blocked by *PID* 9016 who **already read** the content of `file_PID`, meaning the process *9017* wrote its *PID* in the file at a correct time at least for this test.

That's why the problem lies elsewhere but I cannot pinpoint it, the only possibility.

If I manually send the `SIGCONT` signal `kill -SIGCONT 9017` to the *PID* 9017, the script finishes.

Results are correct in this case (this is the correct behaviour I'd like to have) :

---

```
#f1 content
first 9016
next 9017
#f2 content
first 9016
next 9017
#f3 content
first 9016
next 9017
```

Can anyone explain to me why, the first two tests of my script didn't work out as expected and why the last one does not work, I don't see why it shouldn't work as expected. 
But there is probably something about concurrency that I've missed.

Thanks for any help/recommandtion given for this issue.

### Edit 1 : Thanks to @shellter

The code of `write.sh` :

```
#! /bin/bash
# write.sh content
file_PID="./file_PID"
if [ $# -lt 1 ] ; then
  echo "Need at least one parameter"
  exit 1
fi
echo $$ >> "$file_PID"
echo "My PID is : $$"
for elem in "$@" ; do
  if [ ! -e "$elem" ] ; then
    while read pid ;do
    if [ $pid -ne $$ ]; then 
        echo "PID : $$ Sent SIGSTOP to $pid"
            kill -SIGSTOP $pid
    fi
    done < "$file_PID"
    echo first $$ > "$elem"
  else
    echo next $$ >> "$elem"
  fi
  while read pid ; do  
    if [ $pid -ne $$ ]; then
        echo "PID : $$ Sent SIGCONT to $pid"
        kill -SIGCONT $pid
  done < $file_PID
  sed "/^$pid\$/d" $file_PID > $file_PID # Edit : Moved after the while loop allows for more consistent results
done
```

This solves one of the inconsistent results (the one where I have to manually send `SIGCONT` thanks to the comments of @shellter.

But there is still inconsistent issues, the script no longer hangs the terminal but sometimes `SIGSTOP` are sent exactly at the same time :

```
PID : 30608 Sent SIGSTOP to 30607
PID : 30607 Sent SIGSTOP to 30608
PID : 30608 Sent SIGCONT to 30607
PID : 30607 Sent SIGCONT to 30608
```

The order of writing to the files is still messed up as well.

```
#f1 content
first 30607
#f2 content
first 30607
next 30608
#f3 content
first 30608
next 30607
```

Now sometimes I reach the correct execution when I'm lucky and sometimes no.

There are two possibles executions that are right.

None of the scripts writes to the `file_PID` his own *PID* so they both send no signals but this execution seems to give me the correct results.

And the other one, is where both of them write their own *PID* to the `file_PID` and one of them is faster than the other and sends a `SIGSTOP` to the first one.
However the second script begins to continue before the first one finished, so the solution could be to put the `sed` command in the second `while loop` just before sending the signal `SIGCONT` with the `kill` command.

```
            PID : 577 Sent SIGSTOP to 576 
            PID : 577 Sent SIGCONT to 576  # --> Here 577 finished writing to the file.                                                                                                                                            
            PID : 576 Sent SIGSTOP to 577 # Problem here, 576 shouldn't send these signals. 
# since the `sed` command at the end of the script 
# should have taken away the line with the PID of 576 but maybe
# the sed doesn't have enough time to be executed 
# and remove 577, before 576 sends him the SIGSTOP signal.
            PID : 576 Sent SIGCONT to 577
```

### Edit 2 : Actually still the sames issues

I have done some more testing and it seems that even with the suggestion of @shellter, the terminal can be blocked by the script if the second sends a `SIGSTOP` to the first one and then the second one finishes, it sends a `SIGCONT` to the first one.
The first one then sends `SIGSTOP` to the second one before he finishes.

Thus the terminal hangs because the second script has almost finished but was paused by the first script that was resumed and that went to fast and send the `SIGSTOP` to the second one before the second script could remove his own *PID* from the `file_PID` (all this is kinda of hypothetical).

```
My PID is : 30245
My PID is : 30246
PID : 30246 Sent SIGSTOP to 30245
PID : 30246 Sent SIGCONT to 30245
PID : 30245 Sent SIGSTOP to 30246
```

Comment: Each time you run your script, the shell variable `$$` will return a different number, because you have started a new process, which will have a new and different PID than the previous run. I don't think the while loop that runs after `sed "/^$pid\$/d" $file_PID > $file_PID` will have any data to read from that file. AND (separate issue)  it seems that all of your sample files have 1 line of data (maybe 2-3), how can you expect SIGSTOP to have any effect on reading a tiny file. Maybe that could work on a GB+ size file. Unclear why you want to do this.. (leaving for errands now). Good luck

Comment: You're right about the fact that the while read loop after the while have any data I tested that with a `cat $file_PID` just after the while loop, and the file doesn't have any data as you said, I will fix it and comeback later to update my answer. But are signals used only for files that contains lots of data? Is what I'm currently trying to do considered bad practice?

Comment: It's not clear why you want to perform concurrent processing using a shell script. That problem  is normally in the domain of operating systems and coding in C (or Java). If you want to use signals the way they are intended to be used in shell scripting, research the `trap` command in the shell. Billions of lines of shell code are written without including even a `trap` command. (Yes, some could benefit from `trap` processing). But `SIG`s and `trap`s are really for only the most demanding of situations (or employers ;-) ). Good luck.

Comment: It not safe to do `sed "/^$pid\$/d" $file_PID > $file_PID`. You should use a temporary file for the output (+rename when done), or use the `sed` built-in edit in place.

Comment: @shellter I'm currently learning computing science and I was asked by teachers to write such a script probably to understand, why it is insufficient to use signals to do concurrent processing, one solution could be to use a lock file kinda of mechanism, but I'm still asking myself is this really impossible to achieve with signals and also the explanation to why are there these three different outputs.

Comment: OK, that's more like it. I'm glad to hear this is a learning exercize! But a lot to consider here. 1) Did your instructors give you this as a base line code to enhance, or a basic specification, or ??? (and don't post it or add as a comment, I'm just curious). 2) re @dash-o (and my) comment regarding `sed .. ..> $file_PID` ... What do you expect to be in that file at the end? You append the new pid to the file and then you delete right away. 3) .. But ...Getting way ahead of ourselves here. Given that you have a SIGSTOP and SIGCONT, the only way I see that you can demonstrate that ....

Comment: is to have two separate scripts. 1 that is doing a non-stop activity, maybe `printf "%020d\n", $((i++)) > file` inside of a `while true` loop (first write the pid of that script to a file). Now in another script read that pid from the file and execute the STOP and CONT from there while `tail` ing the `file` in a 3rd terminal. That controller script could (theoretcially) manage multiple similar processes and give your concurrent processing. but really again, this is something normally done in C code with the OS. (I am not an expert, by any means in this subject;-)) , so you may find otherwise).

Comment: @shellter Firstly my teacher's code was without any `while loop` and was not sending any signals, and was basically giving non consistent results by default. A question asked by our instructor was that we have to modify the `write.sh` script such that for each call to the script it create a file `file_PID` where it registers its own PID and before writing to a file, sends a STOP to all PIDs already written inside `file_PID`, the sed command is to delete only the PID matched (when the script has finished writing it doesn't need to leave his own pid registered inside `file_PID`.

Comment: @shellter 2) I expect in the end to have nothing left in the file, it is only a temporary file to keep track of who is actually gonna write into a file, at the end both scripts should have ended writing and deleted their own PID from that temporary file, this file is useful only during the concurrent execution of like multiples instances of the same script `write.sh`.

Comment: Also @shellter the instructor also pointed out that this solution he asked us to try to implement, using signals wouldn't be sufficient, he asks why these issue happens, I feel that my script should work, but I can't really explain/ nor make sense of why it doesn't work, why are there these three different executions I have with the same code.

Comment: Wow, my brain hurts! ;-) ... Well it sounds like you have worked within the parameters that your instructor has defined. Without seeing the exact assignment (and having time to think about it), I don't see how I can help much any further :-( . So wishing you ... Good luck.